# Изменить background color у optionsmenu?

Tags: android, android-menu

Сейчас фоновый цвет меню — черный. Хотела изменить его на зеленый. Попробовала `android:background="#00FF00"`. Не меняется.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#00FF00"
>

<item
    android:id="@+id/newrent"
    android:title="@string/action_new_rent"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/deleteme"
    android:title="@string/action_delete_me"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Цвет бекграунда меню надо указывать в стилях `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/green</item>
    ...
</style>
```